# javascript cookies save and load

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this javascript code that changes the style of the website. but this code changes the style only when you click on it. and after you refresh the page it returns to default. I want it to save the users preferences. I really like the code and I do not want to change it with another one. can you please help. I want you to give me the code after adding the cookies code to it!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fullswitch").click(function() {
        $("#chpheader").removeClass("compact");
           $("#imgg").removeClass("compact");
           $("#chpheader").removeClass("original");
        $("#imgg").removeClass("original");
                        $("#chpheader").addClass("normal");
        $("#imgg").addClass("normal");

    });
    $("#compactswitch").click(function() {
        $("#chpheader").addClass("compact");
        $("#imgg").addClass("compact");
        $("#chpheader").removeClass("original");
        $("#imgg").removeClass("original");
        $("#chpheader").removeClass("normal");
        $("#imgg").removeClass("normal");

    });
      $("#originalswitch").click(function() {
        $("#chpheader").addClass("original");
        $("#imgg").addClass("original");
        $("#chpheader").removeClass("compact");
           $("#imgg").removeClass("compact");
                        $("#chpheader").removeClass("normal");
        $("#imgg").removeClass("normal");

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You should add a class to a top-level element such as the root (`<html>`) and style the rest of your document according to that.

```
.style1-p {
    background: blue;
}

.style1-div {
    background: red;
}
```

Should become

```
.style1 p {
    background-blue;
}

.style1 div {
    background-red;
}
```

That way, you only need to change one class, and the whole document will change. It will also mean you only need to save one cookie (that describes that one class), and load it only once.

## [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/64q8A/5/)

EDIT: jsFiddle example updated to include Cookies.

EDIT2: jsFiddle example updated to include multiple stylings!

Comment: He is asking how can he save data on cookies so the class remains the same on every page and after reloading too

Comment: Yes, but the solution would be to do what I told him in the answer. Save one class on the cookie, and apply it to a root level element instead of every single one of the elements separately. I'll add cookies to my example as well

Comment: I do have 3 classes only in my code ... the code looks messy because I have to add the class and remove the other class.

Comment: but I will try to use yours and see =)

Comment: I'll whip up an example once I get near a computer :-)

Comment: @shnisaka I've updated my example to include 3 styles, you can add as many as you'd like too.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will show you the final result on my website after I finish.

Comment: `<div class="original" id="chpheader">
 {section name=pic loop=$pic}
  <a href="{$nsurl}">
        <img class="original" id="imgg" src="" alt=""  />
        </a>
 {/section}
 
</div>`

Comment: as you can see the code above ... I want the <div id="chpheader"> to be changed ... and I want at the same time <img id="imgg"> to be changed at the same time
.
my css is :
`
#chpheader.normal{text-align:center;}
#chpheader.compact{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;}
#chpheader.original{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1000px;}`
`
#imgg.normal {border:0px;}
#imgg.compact{border:0px;max-width:100%; width:100%;}
#imgg.original{border:0px; width:1000px; }`

Comment: Like we are trying to tell you, you don't need to change your class in a hundred different places. Have one parent element and change his class, you can reach you image using `.original #imgg` or `.compact #imgg` or whatever. You should really adopt this approach. Also, if you want to add blocks of code, please edit your question instead of doing it in a comment :)

Comment: but I am trying to change one place in the document not all the document http://www.manga.ae/Naruto/0545/1/ 
I know it is in arabic ... but the last three buttons on the top left if you click on one of them ... It will change how the picture will be displayed

Comment: My point still stands. If you change the view in CSS, you can still use better selectors such a `.standard #imgg { ... }`. Same goes for jQuery.

Comment: nvm .. I got the code that you give me to work perfectly thanks !

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is just a key value pair so you can have one cookie per element you are styling where the key is the id and the value is the class name. In jQuery you would set them like this:

```
$("#chpheader").removeClass("compact");
$.cookie("chpheader", $("#chpheader").attr('class'));
```

and then at the top of your doc ready you would have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.cookie("#chpheader")) {
         $("#chpheader").set("className", $.cookie("#chpheader"));
    }
         ....
```

but word of warning, your code is already a little messy, if you go in and start setting and unsetting cookies all over the place things are going to get really sloppy. I would recommend trying to pull out some functions, and set up the observer pattern. Also, do you really need a normal class? and if you do do you really need to get rid of it when you add the compact class?

Comment: That's assuming he has the cookie plugin for jQuery, which isn't all that certain.

Comment: Thank you for the code.. but this will make the code more messy.